# Different number of sheets of the cover implies there's not covering isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

I have to prove that if $p_1:X_1\rightarrow Y$, $p_2:X_2\rightarrow Y$ are two covering maps (and therefore $X_1$, $X_2$ two covering spaces of $Y$), and the number of sheets is different, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not isomorphic; this is, there's not a covering isomorphism.

I know that a covering isomorphism will exist if and only if for all $x_1\in p_1^{-1}(y)$, $x_2\in p_2^{-1}(y)$ then the subgroups of $\pi (Y,y)$

$\left(p_{1}\right)_{*}\left(\pi_{1}\left(X_{1}, x_{1}\right)\right)$ and $\left(p_{2}\right)_{*}\left(\pi_{1}\left(X_{2}, x_{2}\right)\right)$ are conjugates.

I also know that once fixed $y_{0} \in Y,$ the family of subgroups of $\pi_{1}\left(Y, y_{0}\right)$ given by
$$
\left\{p_{*}\left(\pi_{1}(X, x)\right): x \in p^{-1}\left(\left\{y_{0}\right\}\right)\right\}
$$
is a class of conjugation. Therefore, if the degrees of the covers are different, then I could say that the number of elements in the class of conjugation of $\left(p_{1}\right)_{*}\left(\pi_{1}\left(X_{1}, x_{1}\right)\right)$ is different to the number of elements in the class of conjugation of $\left(p_{2}\right)_{*}\left(\pi_{1}\left(X_{2}, x_{2}\right)\right)$, and in consequence they are not conjugates, which concludes the prove.

Is my firts time working with this topic so I'm not really sure of my conclussions, is my reasoning fine? Did I make any mistake?

PD: $\pi_1(X,x)$ is the foundamental group of $X$ based on $x$, and $\left(p_{1}\right)_{*}\left(\pi\left(X, x\right)\right)$ is the group homomorphism induced by $p$.

Comment: What is the cover degree? The number of sheets?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a covering map $p : X \to Y$, the number of sheets $s(y)$ at a point $y \in Y$ is the cardinality of the fiber $p^{-1}(y)$. The function $s$ is locally constant, thus $Y$ splits into pairwise disjoint open $Y_\alpha \subset Y$ such that the number of sheets is constant on each $Y_\alpha$. Let us assume that $s$ is constant on $Y$; otherwise it does not make sense to speak about **the** number of sheets of $p$. We could also consider all $Y_\alpha$ separately, but this does not bring an advantage.

Now consider  two covering maps $p_i : X_i \to Y$ having a definite number of sheets. Assume $h : X_1 \to X_2$ is an isomorphism of covering spaces. This means that $h$ is a homeomorphism satisfying $p_2h = p_1$. We conclude that for each $y \in Y$ we get a bijection $h_y : p_1^{-1}(y)  \to  p_2^{-1}(y) $. This means that $p_1, p_2$ have the same number of sheets.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use the characterization, but this approach seems more direct and easier.